# I want to integrate mailchimp with wordpress without using plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have used this after my form.But my entry does not go to the mailchimp account. Please tell me if anything missing. Please refer the below code.

```
<?php

// SUBSCRIBE TO MAILING LIST OPTION - ADD TO MAILCHIMP USING API
if ($_POST['emailUpdates'] == 'Yes')
{
    // Include Mailchimp API class
    require_once('MCAPI.class.php');

    // Your API Key: http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
    $api = new MCAPI('xxxxxxxxx-us15');

    // Your List Unique ID: http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/ (Click "settings")
    $list_id = "xxxxxxx";

    // Variables in your form that match up to variables on your subscriber
    // list. You might have only a single 'name' field, no fields at all, or more
    // fields that you want to sync up.
    $merge_vars = array(
        'FNAME' => $_POST['signup_first_name'],
        'LNAME' => $_POST['signup_last_name']
    );

    // SUBSCRIBE TO LIST
    if ($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_POST['signup_user_email'], $merge_vars) === true)
    {
        $mailchimp_result = 'Success! Check your email to confirm sign up.';
    }
    else
    {
        $mailchimp_result = 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integrate mailchimp form without using sdk class

```
 $email= $_POST["email"];

$api_key = "dsfdfdsfdsdsfsfdgdfg-us15"; //api key
$list_id = "2f35dfgdgffec5c2"; // list id


  $url = 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey='.$api_key.'&id='.$list_id.'&email[email]='.$email.'&double_optin=false&send_welcome=false';
echo callMailchimp($url);
function callMailchimp($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-PHP-cURL-to-access-the-new-MailChimp-API-v3-0

Comment: NOw currently are you using wordpress?

Comment: Yes,I am using wordpress

Comment: $url = 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=apikey&id=ee3c45310c&email[email]='.$email.'&double_optin=false&send_welcome=false';

Comment: i just give example let me know last 4 gidit of your api key

Comment: And currently are you trying form submit using ajax @Priya2026 ?

Comment: Yes,there is no form action in my form

Comment: If i use static email in url then it is working.But when use $email it is not working

Comment: @hello you paste this url in browser

Comment: @Priya2026 and https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/  here us15 is last 4 of your api key

Comment: Yes,working. But only for static url.Entry goes to the mailchimp account.

Comment: Error: {"status":"error","code":-100,"name":"ValidationError","error":"An email address must contain a single @"}

Comment: If I use api key,list id and static email in url then its work.But $api_key,list_id ,$email is not working.

Comment: @Priya2026 plz send me last 4 digit of your api key  so i will provide to you correct url

Comment: @Priya2026 can you please delete your api key to here, i give me suggestion don't publish your api key in publicly

Comment: have you any skype id ? so i can easily give sugestion

Answer (score 0):

try to add the list id with a single quote this is example what i used for my form

```
<?php
    require_once 'inc/MCAPI.class.php';
    $api = new MCAPI('xxxxxxxxxxx-us15');
    $merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>$_POST["fname"], 'LNAME'=>$_POST["lname"]);

    // Submit subscriber data to MailChimp
    // For parameters doc, refer to: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php
    $retval = $api->listSubscribe( 'xxxxx', $_POST["email"], $merge_vars, 'html', false, true );

    if ($api->errorCode){
        echo "<h4>Please try again.</h4>";
    } else {
        echo "<h4>Thank you, you have been added to our mailing list.</h4>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have wordpress structure. Where do I add MCAPI.php file?

Comment: check my another answer with email filed which works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used for one of my project I change some details like id and api_key as you can see I made custom shortcode for this and also you will see the location of user from where they fill up the form by IP

[mail_chimp_form]

```
<?php 
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MAIL CHIMP API
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function rudr_mch_subscribe() {
    $list_id = 'XXXXX';
    $api_key = 'XXXXXXXX-us15';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
    $cnt=$details->country; 
    $result = json_decode(rudr_mailchimp_subscriber_status($_POST['email'], 'subscribed', $list_id, $api_key, array('FNAME' => $firstname, 'LNAME' => $lastname),array('country_code'=>'".$cnt."')));
    // print_r($result);
            if ($resul->status == 400) {
                foreach ($result->errors as $error) {
                    echo '<p>Error: ' . $error->message . '</p>';
                }
            } elseif ($result->status == 'subscribed') {
                echo 'Thanks for Subscribing!';
            }
            die;
        }
add_action('wp_ajax_mailchimpsubscribe', 'rudr_mch_subscribe');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mailchimpsubscribe', 'rudr_mch_subscribe');
function rudr_mailchimp_subscriber_status( $email, $status, $list_id, $api_key, $merge_fields = array('FNAME' => '','LNAME' => ''),$location=array('country_code'=>'') ){
       function getUserIP()
    {
        $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $client;
        }
        elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
        {
            $ip = $forward;
        }
        else
        {
            $ip = $remote;
        }

        return $ip;
    } 
    $ipAddr = getUserIP();
    $geoIP  = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/$ipAddr"), true);
    $lati=$geoIP['latitude'];
    $long=$geoIP['longitude'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
    $cnt=$details->country;
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $api_key,
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => $status,
        'merge_fields' =>$merge_fields,
        'location' =>array(
               'latitude' =>$lati,
                'longitude' => $long,
                'country_code'=>$cnt
          ) 
    );
    $mch_api = curl_init(); // initialize cURL connection

    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($data['email_address'])));
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode( 'user:'.$api_key )));
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the API response
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'); // method PUT
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($mch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) ); // send data in json

    $result = curl_exec($mch_api);
    return $result;
}
function mail_chimp_code(){
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

?>
 <div class="chimpform">
   <div class="chimpform_inenr">
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" id="mailchimp">
    <!-- for my website the site_url() function returns https://rudrastyh.com -->
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last name" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="email" name="email" id="mce-EMAIL" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_email ?>" placeholder="Your email address" required/>

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimpsubscribe" />
    <!-- we need action parameter to receive ajax request in WordPress -->

    <div class="mail_left"><button>YES! I WANT TO IMPROVE MY CAREER</button></div>
    <div class="mail_right"><button class="pum-close popmake-close" type="button"/>NO THANKS, I DON'T WANT ANY HELP</button></div>
  </form>
   <p class="status"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('#mailchimp').submit(function(){
        var mailchimpform = $(this);
        $.ajax({ 
            url:mailchimpform.attr('action'),
            type:'POST',
            data:mailchimpform.serialize(), 
            success:function(data){
                  $('#mailchimp').hide();
                 $('p.status').text(data);
                document.getElementById("mailchimp").reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<?php
}// End some_random_code()
add_shortcode( 'mail_chimp_form', 'mail_chimp_code' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a sync from WordPress to Mailchimp without any code or plugins using zzBots.

You can read more about this sync here: https://www.zzbots.com/community/how-to/sync-new-wordpress-users-to-mailchimp

This specific sync, or integration, is designed to automatically sync new WordPress users to Mailchimp as new subscribers. Although, you can use zzBots to integrate these two app together in many different ways.

Disclaimer: I am affiliated with zzBots

Comment: You appear to be the author of the linked article.
When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam.
Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.